# Tool strips are joined back to back on resizing the tool strip container

Tags: winforms, c#-3.0

I have a tool strip container in which i have two tool strips that are vertically aligned on the right panel of container and between these two tool strips I have a track bar. When i open the project as it is, then the form looks fine but as soon as i resize the form, the two tool strips join back to back and hence tool strip 2 hides underneath the track bar. How to resolve this??

Comment: I've seen this question before.  Did you just delete your old one?  How many answers were lost?

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure that all three controls are docked to the right side of the form.

I've tried to reproduce the situation that you see and it works fine when all three controls are docked.

Comment: Feel free to edit your post by adding some code. Specifically, we should see what's going on in your InitializeComponent function with your 2 toolstrips and your trackbar. Also, any additional code that you're calling on these controls outside of InitializeComponent.